# Is 'HtmlProperties' NOT supported in .NET Framework 4.5?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I've been studying about 'Coded UI' by following a step by step instruction on [Hand-Coding a Coded UI Test](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/02/12/hand-coding-a-coded-ui-test.aspx). However, as I was typing the code, Visual Studio did not recognize `HtmlProperties`  .
Here's some of the code:

```
UITestControl qEdit = new UITestControl(browserWindow);
qEdit.TechnologyName = "Web";
qEdit.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlProperties.Edit.ControlType, ControlType.Edit.Name,
HtmlProperties.Edit.Id, "sb_form_q");
qEdit.SetProperty(HtmlProperties.Edit.Text, "MSFT");
```

By the way, I'm using Visual Studio 2012, .NET Framework 4.5.
Hope my question makes sense. Thanks!

---Intern Here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code example is deprecated after several releases. Here is the same code updated:

```
UITestControl qEdit = new UITestControl(browserWindow);
qEdit.TechnologyName = "Web";
qEdit.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Name",
"Id", "sb_form_q");
qEdit.SetProperty("Text", "MSFT");
```

Edit to add:
I know there were more, but this is the only reference I could find. There was an update to VS2010 sometime after the original tutorial was written that was code breaking.
[MSDN hand coding thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e51c8b6-5660-4f68-97a5-1208b56fe592/i-need-tutorial-hand-coding-in-coded-ui-test?forum=vsautotest)

[Found it!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/02/10/visual-studio-2010-rc-is-now-available.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I get an exception while running the test. But thanks for helping :) I already found the solution.

Comment: I'll still consider this as the answer because it really answers my question. Thanks! :)

Comment: @yonidtm Can you provide a link to where the deprecation is discussed and to the now preferred style?

Comment: Thanks @yonidtm . I also did a search and only found that page, hence my request.

Comment: I had more references back when we started using 2010, trying to find them but my archived email search is not cooperating, sorry! They had a whole thing about how to update code to account for the breaking update, will keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution. This is what I did:

```
UITestControl qEdit = new UITestControl(browserWindow);
qEdit.TechnologyName = "Web";
qEdit.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, "sb_form_q");
qEdit.SetProperty(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Text, "MSFT");
```